# How to remove folders by name pattern hierarchically?

Tags: bash

The hierarchy I have:

```
root
|__ project1
|   |__ node_modules
|   package.json
|__ project2
|   |__ node_modules
|   package.json
```

This can be pretty straightforward, but how to remove only `node_modules` folders from `root` folder by using bash?

P.S.: `node_modules` folders are not empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find root -name node_modules -type d -exec rm -r {} +
```

This matches all directories in `root` and adds them to the arguments list to `rm -r`.

I would suggest changing `rm -r {}` for `echo {}` (or removing the `-exec` part entirely) to make sure that it is going to do the right thing first!

If your shell supports it, you could also use `globstar` like this:

```
rm -r root/**/node_modules/
```

The glob recursively matches any paths ending in `/node_modules/`.

In an interactive bash shell, this will be enabled by default but in a script you need to do `shopt -s globstar` in order to make this work. Again, changing `rm -r` to `echo` shows you what is going to happen first.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
find root -name node_modules | xargs rm -rf
```

If you don't want to remove files named `node_modules` you should add `-type d` that ensures `node_modules` are directories.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
$ find root -name node_modules -type d | while read dir; do rm -r "$dir"; done
```

This will also work with filenames containing spaces.

<sup>(I always tend to forget the exact syntax of the `-exec` option to `find`, that's why I prefer to pipe to `while`. I also think it's more in line with the "do one thing and do it well" philosophy.)</sup>